# Matching Perspective for Augmented Reality (Back-Camera's FOV)

Tags: google-project-tango

I have been trying to setup for augmented reality game and am having trouble matching the real and digital perspectives... Any advice? Also, do you know Back-Camera's FOV for google tango?

Answer (score 0):

the most precise way of getting camera's FOV is to query the camera instrinsics through the Tango API. [Here](https://developers.google.com/project-tango/apis/c/reference/group/camera#group___camera_1ga61f047f290983da9d16522371977cecf) is the c/c++ API pointer.

Also, Project Tango provide example of implementing proper AR experience, you can check out the code on github ([c++ AR example](https://github.com/googlesamples/tango-examples-c/tree/master/augmented-reality-jni-example), [unity AR example](https://github.com/googlesamples/tango-examples-unity/tree/master/UnityExamples/Assets/TangoExamples/ExperimentalAugmentedReality))

Comment: Hello, I have used the camera intrinsics Vertical FOV and things seem almost right now... But do u have any idea on wether to use vertical or horizontal fov in unity for artificial reality applications?

Comment: Yes found it: it is the vertical FOV. (http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera-fieldOfView.html)

Comment: I think the better method is to use customized projection matrix, because the actually camera's intrinsics is off center projection. You cannot do the off center projection use the Unity camera FOV function. Here is the sample code: https://github.com/googlesamples/tango-examples-unity/blob/master/UnityExamples/Assets/TangoExamples/ExperimentalAugmentedReality/Scripts/ARScreen.cs#L303